# Filtering and then Ordering

Tags: sorting, filter

This is a database about flights, one column has the time delay a flight had.

In the first line of code, I'm filtering all the flights that had more than 2 hours of flight

```
    delaymorethan2 <- filter(flights, arr_delay >=2)
```

In the second line, I subtract the arr_delay vector and sort it

```
    sorted <- sort(delaymorethan2$arr_delay, decreasing=TRUE)
```

In the third line of code, I get an error when I try to get a subset from the table and order it by arr_delay

```
  delayedtable <- subset(delaymorethan2, arr_delay %in% sorted)
```

But the table is not showing sorted by arr_delay.

---

If trying using order(), also it says object not found

```
    newdata <- delaymorethan2[order(arr_delay),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the decreasing parameter in order(), I was using descending.

Solution:

```
  delaymorethan2 <- filter(flights, arr_delay >=2)
  ordered <- order(delaymorethan2$arr_delay, decreasing = T)
  delaymorethan2[ordered,]
```